# When an iOS app crashes, how does it affect the operation of the OS?

Tags: ios, performance, crash

I was just curious. What happens to the OS when an iOS app crashes?

I know that it creates a crash log, but does it add any extra diagnostic files to the system? Does it affect core services that run to keep the OS running smoothly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It creates a crash log. You can see them in the XCode Organizer/Devices pane under the Device Logs part of the device. Some information can also be written in the device console. The system itself (as well as other apps) is protected and should not be affected unless the crash is in fact happening at a lower level part in one of Apple components. But it is very very very very seldom (all bugs where I once thought "this is a bug in the OS" ended up always be mine)

Answer (score 2):

It should not affect the system unless the crash occurred in the code of an Apple framework. It is no different than when the OS terminates an app.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: If you are not using non public APIs then NO.

Comment: It is VERY unlikely that the OS is influenced by any api call but strictly not impossible